# Avoiding Postback on ASP.NET / C#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, postback

I'm using ajax so I can load the content of the page two on the page one . I'm doing this with javascript code (cannot user UpdatePanel) .
The problem is :
I need to execute some c# code , and ONLY AFTER that , execute the javascript code to open the page . But when the javascript is executed , the page had postback , which means the page one is gone . So , I REALLY need to stop the postback . Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 3):

can't you use a page method web service and call that to execute your c# code - that will return you to your javascript.

Comment: yah, this is one possibility.

Answer (score 0):

not really got what u mean by stopping postback...

u are able to handle postbacks

```
if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            //ur c# code here
            //and after u are done with c# call/exec js
        }
```

Comment: That prevents some code from being executed , but does not avoid the postback .
I have a page inside another page . When the postback happens , only the inner page remains .